# Backfilling a pandas dataframe missed the first month

Tags: pandas, datetime, dataframe

I have a pandas df or irrigation demand data that has daily values from 1900 to 2099.  I resampled the df to get the monthly average and then resampled and backfilled the monthly averages on a daily frequency, so that the average daily value for each month, was input as the daily value for every day of that month.

My problem is that the first month was not backfilled and there is only a value for the last day of that month (1900-01-31).

Here is my code, any suggestions on what I am doing wrong?

```
I2 = pd.DataFrame(IrrigDemand, columns = ['Year', 'Month', 'Day', 'IrrigArea_1', 'IrrigArea_2','IrrigArea_3','IrrigArea_4','IrrigArea_5'],dtype=float)  

# set dates as index 
I2.set_index('Year')   

# make a column of dates in datetime format
dates = pd.to_datetime(I2[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])       

# add the column of dates to df
I2['dates'] = pd.Series(dates, index=I2.index) 

# set dates as index of df
I2.set_index('dates')                                                    

# delete the three string columns replaced with datetime values
I2.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'],inplace=True,axis=1)    

# calculate the average daily value for each month 
I2_monthly_average = I2.reset_index().set_index('dates').resample('m').mean()                           
I2_daily_average = I2_monthly_average.resample('d').bfill()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is problem first `day` is not added by `resample('m')`, so necessary add it manually:

```
# make a column of dates in datetime format and assign to index
I2.index = pd.to_datetime(I2[['Year', 'Month', 'Day']])       

# delete the three string columns replaced with datetime values
I2.drop(['Year', 'Month', 'Day'],inplace=True,axis=1)    

# calculate the average daily value for each month 
I2_monthly_average = I2.resample('m').mean()   

first_day = I2_monthly_average.index[0].replace(day = 1)
I2_monthly_average.loc[first_day] = I2_monthly_average.iloc[0]

I2_daily_average = I2_monthly_average.resample('d').bfill()
```

Sample:

```
rng = pd.date_range('2017-04-03', periods=10, freq='20D')
I2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(10)}, index=rng)  
print (I2)
            a
2017-04-03  0
2017-04-23  1
2017-05-13  2
2017-06-02  3
2017-06-22  4
2017-07-12  5
2017-08-01  6
2017-08-21  7
2017-09-10  8
2017-09-30  9
```

---

```
I2_monthly_average = I2.resample('m').mean()
print (I2_monthly_average)
              a
2017-04-30  0.5
2017-05-31  2.0
2017-06-30  3.5
2017-07-31  5.0
2017-08-31  6.5
2017-09-30  8.5

first_day = I2_monthly_average.index[0].replace(day = 1)
I2_monthly_average.loc[first_day] = I2_monthly_average.iloc[0]
print (I2_monthly_average)
              a
2017-04-30  0.5
2017-05-31  2.0
2017-06-30  3.5
2017-07-31  5.0
2017-08-31  6.5
2017-09-30  8.5
2017-04-01  0.5 <- added first day

I2_daily_average = I2_monthly_average.resample('d').bfill()
print (I2_daily_average.head())
              a
2017-04-01  0.5
2017-04-02  0.5
2017-04-03  0.5
2017-04-04  0.5
2017-04-05  0.5
```